# What can I do when "100vh" meets Chrome mobile tool bar

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive

When I set a div like this

```
    .exampleDiv {
      height:100vh;
    }
```

It works well on desktops
But on Chrome mobile, the moment I scroll the screen, **the Chrome tool bar will appear, thus leading the expampleDiv' height change to: 

100vh-touchbar'height**

which is not smooth and is very wired.
So what should I do to make "100vh" not changing with the tool bar?

Comment: I don't think this would be possible with plain css. It may be possible with JavaScript however I am not sure.

Comment: if you facing this problem you could use a media query to solve it or you may look out this blog https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/

Comment: I think it's better not to use "vh" when it comes to small screen.